# What explains best the CAPropertyAnimation animationWithKeyPath: parameter?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I'd like to have a better understanding of this parameter in

```
+ (id)animationWithKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
```

They just say: "The key path of the property to be animated."

In some example snippets I see things like:

```
CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];

CAKeyframeAnimation *animatedIconAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"frameOrigin"];
```

Is there a list or rule of thumb for determining the correct key path parameter? i.e. when I want to animate the width of a frame, what kind of rules would I have to follow to get to the correct key path parameter string?

Answer (score 18):

Well for example if you're animating the layer property of a UIView, then check out CALayer.h - here you can find the property opacity, and the inline doc mentions that it is animatable. Or frameOrigin in NSView.

A bunch of properties are animatable, for iphone:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html

and mac:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimProps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005942-SW4

And then there are some extensions:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/KVCAdditions.html

to give you:

[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];

Comment: Update link to all animatable properties: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html

Answer (score 6):

To understand what a "key path" is, you should learn a little about Key-Value Coding (KVC). To start with, you should read [Key-Value Coding Fundamentals](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-183455), but ultimately you should read through the whole [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html). Once you understand KVC, other concepts like Key-Value Observing (KVO) will be much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath Types

When using the `CABasicAnimation` from the `QuartzCore Framework` in `Objective-C`, you have to specify an `animationWithKeyPath`.  This is a long string and is not easily listed in the `CABasicAnimation`, `CAPropertyAnimation`, or the `CAAnimation` class.  I ended up finding a handy chart within the Core Animation Programming guide in Apple’s iPhone OS Reference Library.  Hope this helps save someone time, at least it will for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have used animationWithKeyPath:@"hidden" and animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd". They are not listed in the link below, So I wonder there must be many more.